# Passing timestamp parameter to function in Postgresql 10.6

Tags: postgresql, function, timestamp

I'm building this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION qradar21(cliente_in VARCHAR(50), fecha_inicio timestamp, fecha_fin timestamp) RETURNS TABLE(empresa varchar, fecha timestamp, fuente text, total float) AS $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY
            SELECT qradar_eventos_detalle.empresa, qradar_eventos_detalle.fecha, eventos->>'fuente' AS fuente, sum((eventos->>'total')::float) AS total FROM public.qradar_eventos_detalle
            WHERE qradar_eventos_detalle.empresa = 'cliente_in'
            AND qradar_eventos_detalle.fecha BETWEEN 'fecha_inicio' AND 'fecha_fin'
            GROUP BY qradar_eventos_detalle.empresa, qradar_eventos_detalle.fecha, qradar_eventos_detalle.eventos
            ORDER BY total DESC;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

And calling it with:

```
SELECT * FROM qradar21('BancoXXX', '2018-12-29 12:00:00', '2019-03-03 07:00:00');
```

Getting this message:

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: «fecha_inicio»
LINE 3:    AND qradar_eventos_detalle.fecha BETWEEN 'fecha_inicio' A...

If I change the function to use directly the date (AND qradar_eventos_detalle.fecha BETWEEN '2018-12-29 12:00:00' AND '2018-12-30 07:00:00'), it works great.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong... Does anyone know how to pass this "timestamp without time zone" format to the function?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Unrelated, but: it's more efficient to write functions that only contain a simple query as `language sql` rather than `language plpgsql`

Comment: I sure will. I'm just starting to work with postgresql and i appreciate any advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function uses string literals, rather then referencing the parameters.

You need to remove the single quotes around your parameter names:

```
WHERE qradar_eventos_detalle.empresa = cliente_in --<< no quotes here!
AND qradar_eventos_detalle.fecha BETWEEN fecha_inicio AND fecha_fin
                                         ^
                                        or here
```

---

When you call it, it's also better to use proper timestamp literal:

```
SELECT * 
FROM qradar21('BancoXXX', timestamp '2018-12-29 12:00:00', timestamp '2019-03-03 07:00:00');
```

Comment: 2 days spent looking for the solution you wrote in 2 seconds